# Is there a way to improve this use of reduce?

Tags: javascript

This is a common pattern I am using in my application.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'item1',
    condition: true
  },
  {
    id: 1235,
    name: 'item2',
    condition: false
  },
  {
    id: 1236,
    name: 'item3',
    condition: true
  }
]

//filters into array of ids of objects that meet condition
const onlyIds = data.reduce((idArr, item) => {
  item.condition && idArr.push(item.id)
  return idArr;
}, [])

console.log(onlyIds);
```

I am curious if there are optimizations I could be aware of?

Some optimizations I’m curious about are, fallibility,  readability, performance, and, eloquence.  Are there other optimizations I should be considering in general?

Comment: Probably a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need reduce here

```
data.filter(({ condition }) => condition).map(({ id }) => id)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve the same with `filter` and `map`. I usually use `reduce` when I want to take one structure such as a list, and turn it into something like an object. Heres an example of `filter` and `map`

```
const onlyIds = data
    .filter(f => f.condition)
    .map(f => f.id);
```

The `filter` and `map` will each iterate the array however, so if the array in question is massive, this may have performance implications.

Comment: Wouldn't this iterate over the array twice?

Comment: Though filter and map seems to be the right functions that fits in to achieve the desired result, however, what about the performance? PS: I have not down-voted

Comment: Yes it would iterate twice.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal - Depends on the size of the array for performance. If the array in question is the actual size, then don't worry about it. If we're talking millions of elements, then worry about it.

Comment: Agreed. However, in my opinion if we are giving a solution with more loops / iterations than the attempt in question, we can specify that as a note.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal - Can't argue with that :) Made a note of this in the answer.

Comment: However, the criteria listed were "fallibility, readability, performance, and, eloquence".  So should we also detail that it improves the other three?

Comment: @tymeJV - Thanks mate!

Comment: @ScottSauyet - hahaha.. That's not a topic for discussion / debate mate! I will leave the decision upto you! :)